# Recreate an Ember.js Component view element

Tags: ember.js

The documentation for Ember.Component's tagName property says: "The tag name is only used when an element is first created. If you change the tagName for an element, **you must destroy and recreate the view element**."

How do I do that ? Here's my code :

```
{{#each sortedBricks as |brick|}}
  {{brick-block brick=brick tagName=brick.tagName}}
{{/each}}
```

I want the view element of the brick-block component to change if the value of brick.tagName changes.

Comment: Depending on how you mutate "sortedBricks", it might re-render the whole array, thus destroying and re-creating the components. I like @TameBadger's suggestion of the `{{component}}` helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_detaching-and-tearing-down-component-elements-with-code-willdestroyelement-code)
You'll have to trigger a teardown, by either using something like this

```
{{#if falseBool}}
  {{my-component}}
{{/if}}
```

or navigating to a new route, or quoting the guides
"Component teardown can be triggered by a number of different conditions"

I demonstrate the above example in the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/429726d9245c412ca714eecf24053862?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.brick-block.hbs)

Can you perhaps elaborate on why you want to switch out tagNames like this ?

I think you might be able to achieve something similar by making use of dynamically loading components, which would look something like this:

```
{{#each blocks as |block|}}
  {{component block.componentTagname}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of toggling visibility. Its works very well